# перемещение камеры в unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

хочу сделать перемещение камеры через функцию OnBecameInvisible() и написал такой код

```
    public Camera Camera;
    public int y = 31, x = 55;
    void OnBecameInvisible()
    {
        if (Camera.transform.position.x > transform.position.x)
            Camera.transform.position = new Vector3(Camera.transform.position.x - x, Camera.transform.position.y, Camera.transform.position.z);
        else if (Camera.transform.position.x < transform.position.x)
            Camera.transform.position = new Vector3(Camera.transform.position.x + x, Camera.transform.position.y, Camera.transform.position.z);
        else if(Camera.transform.position.y > transform.position.y)
            Camera.transform.position = new Vector3(Camera.transform.position.x, Camera.transform.position.y - y, Camera.transform.position.z);
        else if(Camera.transform.position.y < transform.position.y)
            Camera.transform.position = new Vector3(Camera.transform.position.x, Camera.transform.position.y + y, Camera.transform.position.z);
    }
```

и понял что это будет работать только по горизонтали.

не могу пока придумать как разделить проверку на:  по вертикали , по горизонтали .

Answer (score 0):

Просто сохраняйте изменение координат в переменные:

```
var deltaX = 0f;
var deltaY = 0f;

if (Camera.transform.position.x < transform.position.x)
    deltaX = x;
else if (Camera.transform.position.x > transform.position.x)
    deltaX = -x;

if (Camera.transform.position.y < transform.position.y)
    deltaY = y;
else if (Camera.transform.position.y > transform.position.y)
    deltaY = -y;

Camera.transform.position = Camera.transform.position + new Vector3(deltaX, deltaY, 0);
```

Comment: теперь камера двигается только по диагоналям

Comment: Вы просили показать как разделить проверку по вертикали и по горизонтали, я показал. Что именно Вы хотите я не знаю, я дал вам идею. Эксперементируйте!

Comment: ладно . и на этом спасибо )